# Qt: format an integer in a QString

Tags: c++, qt, integer, format, qstring

I would like to format an integer in a `QString`. I would like to always have 6 numbers.
For example "1" should be "000001" and "12" should be "000012".

I try to do like with `printf(%06d, number)`. So I wrote this

`QString test;
 test = QString("%06d").arg(QString::number(i));
 qDebug()<<test;`

i is implemented in a loop `for`.
But it does not work since I have:

> "0d" 
>   "1d"
>   "2d"
>   "3d"...

Does anyone know how to do this please?

Comment: If you read the documentation of QString::arg(), you will understand the results you're getting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

String's argument support doesn't work like printf. It's all documented. What you want is:

```
QString test = QString("%1").arg(i, 6, 10, QLatin1Char('0'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
int a = 12;
QString test = QString("%1").arg(a, 6, 'g', -1, '0');
qDebug() << test; // outputs "000012"
```

Comment: This unnecessarily uses the `arg` overload for doubles. It will fail spectacularly if the platform `int` is a 64 bit type, or if the declaration ever gets changed to `qint64`. By failing spectacularly I mean that there will be digits in the result that are simply wrong. It will fail just the same if the platform's `double` type is equal to `float` and happens to be 32 bits wide (as allowed by the standard). So this is pretty much unportable and not recommended at all.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the documentation for [QTextStream](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qtextstream.html). There are a number of settings for formatting as well as a number of handy manipulators. This is analogous to the text manipulators from STL `iostream`